Complete Boolean Algebra and Distributivity
Thear are two facts about Boolean algebra:

Every Boolean algebra is isomorphic to an algebra of sets. (Stone's Representation Thm)

Every complete algebra of sets is completely distributive. (said in Jech's book)


For completely distributivity, I mean
$$
\bigwedge_{\alpha<\kappa}\bigvee_{i\in I_\alpha}u_{\alpha,i}=\bigvee_{f\in\prod_{\alpha<\kappa}I_\alpha}\bigwedge_{\alpha<\kappa}u_{\alpha,f(\alpha)}.
$$
Then combine these two facts it seems that every complete Boolean algebra is completely distributive (?).
However, I find a result saying that a complete Boolean algebra is completely distributive iff it's atomic, i.e., it's a CABA (complete atomic Boolean algebra). In case it's isomorphic to a power set.
There must be something wrong. From this post, an algebra of sets
may not use $\cap$ as its infinitive meet. But then how does fact 2 hold?

I presume, by $2$, the author means “a complete algebra of sets” as an algebra of sets which uses set-theoretic intersection and union as infinitive meet and join, in which case it is clear that complete distributivity holds.
For a concrete example of the failure of complete distributivity, consider, say the measure algebra of the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0, 1]$, which is a complete Boolean algebra. For each $t \in (0, 1]$, let $I_t$ be the collection of (equivalence classes of) measurable sets with measure exactly $t$. Clearly $\bigvee_{u \in I_t} u = [0, 1]$, but the infinitive meet of a collection consisting of one element from each $I_t$ is $\varnothing$. So,
$$\bigwedge_{t \in (0, 1]} \bigvee_{u \in I_t} u = [0, 1] \neq \varnothing = \bigvee_{f \in \prod_{t \in (0, 1]} I_t} \bigwedge_{t \in (0, 1]} f(t)$$
